# Get average of multiple threads running in a loop

Tags: python-3.x, multithreading

Is there a way to get the average of all the requests. I am able to get the response time per execution as below(running as a loop for a set duration). But is there a way to sum all of these and get the average?

Output:
Thread 0
Thread 1
request: 1 ResponseTime: 0.003963258999999941
request: 0 ResponseTime: 0.005142219999999975
Thread 0

I basically want to get the get the average of all the 4 entries above. NOTE: i am using
start = time.process_time() & request_time = time.process_time() - start 
to get the response time.
Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the thread termination leads to process termination then you need to store all the results to a file a create a separate code to calculate the average using the values in the file.

If the process keeps running even after the threads die then you can can do it in the following manner.

```
# Moving variable to keep track of average - global variable
average = 0

# Moving variable to keep track of number of threads that ran so far - global variable
n = 0

# On thread completion
def request(host, url, req_id):
    global average
    global n
    # Your code here 

    average = (average*n + new_thread_time) / (n+1)
    n += 1
```

Note that these variables need to be synchronized among threads.

Comment: @naivecode- thanks for the response but looks like the average is just printing out the response time and not really keeping a track of the number of threads. ```Req: 0 Status: 200OK ResponseTime: 0.004560859000000028 Average: 0.004560859000000028
Req: 1 Status: 200OK ResponseTime: 0.004666477999999974 Average: 0.004666477999999974 ```

Comment: Can you post the code as to how you are using this? It is hard to indicate anything otherwise.

Comment: Hi @naivecoder- i edited the original post with the code above

Comment: @Contraboy you need to declare the average and n as global variables and use them inside your functions. I am editing the post for that.

Comment: @naivecoder- thanks for your help!! it works as expected!!